# asn1 error with bouncy castle api

Tags: java, parsing, bouncycastle, asn.1

I  have a asn1 parser written in java with Bouncy Castle API. It works well and It worked well for 2 years parsing million of files.

Now for a particular file I have an exception but i can not understand exactly where and why it is generated. Maybe this is just a corrupt stream but I would like to be able to do a low level analysis and understand what the exception is about.

Someone has experience with these classes?

Code

```
ASN1InputStream stream =new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                (byte[]) asn1));
stream.readObject();
```

Stack trace

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BOOLEAN value should have 1 byte in it
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Boolean.fromOctetString(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.createPrimitiveDERObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1StreamParser.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1StreamParser.readVector(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1StreamParser.readTaggedObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at com.xx.yyy.parser.Asn1Parser.parseHorizontal(Asn1Parser.java:384)

Comment: can you share the asn1 file ? It seems it is not correctly encoded.

Comment: You can download it from address: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=95619810813110768147 Is a big file with many records the problem is in record 2387 If I did not make mistakes in the record division

Answer (score 1):

You can know what the exception means just downloading bouncycastle source from its web.
And then follow the files shown in the stack trace, in this case ASN1Boolean.java.
This exception means the ASN1 has included a tag BOOLEAN with a field with length != 1.

I cannot download your file since I have this address blocked. 
Anyway, try decoding it with another tool to ensure it is an ASN.1 encoding error.

Comment: Do you have some advice for  tools to translate ASN1?

Comment: I change the address of the file ..if you want you can download now https://wetransfer.com/downloads/884f3e410ad80e29f5e01a82fc0c0e9f20170429144140/6f28a7

Comment: Maybe you can use https://lapo.it/asn1js/   . But first you have to get the affected record.